# Объясните принцип работы Interface в java

Tags: java

Добрый день. 
Есть интерфейс, например

```
public interface MyInterface {
    MyClassTestInt update (Long id, String user, Long groupId);
}
```

Есть некий класс

```
public class MyClassTestInt implements Serializable {
    private Long id = 3L;
    private String name;

    public MyClassTestInt(MyClassTestInt buf) {
        if (buf != null) {
            this.id = buf.getId();
            this.name = buf.name;
        }
    }

    public MyClassTestInt() {
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

И есть вот такой класс

```
public class NyRelClass {
    MyInterface myInterface;

    public void up(Long id, String name, Long groupId) {
       MyClassTestInt myClassTestInt = myInterface.update(id, name, groupId);
    }
}
```

Я вот никак не пойму, вот эту строку

```
MyClassTestInt myClassTestInt = myInterface.update(id, name, groupId);
```

Каким образом мы получим объект `myClassTestInt`, вызвав метод у интерфейса?
Я так понимаю его же где-то реализовать надо, и переопределить методы его, но тут, как он создает объект?

Comment: Найдите в коде, где инициализируется переменная `myInterface` и все станет ясно.

Comment: В том то и дело, что не понятно где, я сделал тест реализацию реального проекта, где все вот так же как я написал, просто упростил немного. Но в проекте используется Spring, т.е. перед MyInterface myInterface; стоит аннотация @Autowired.

Comment: Я нашел другой класс, который реализует этот интерфейс. И так есть как раз такой же метод переопределнный, который возвращает тип MyClassTestInt. Может это как раз оно? Мне вот именно понять бы эту схему, она ли это. Очень уж сложны для понимания на начальных уровнях эти Интерфейсы

Comment: Это не у интерфейса вызывается метод, а у экземпляра класса..... объявление которого как раз выше `MyInterface myInterface;` а ты его где-то создаешь и потом метод вызываешь уже у него

Comment: Ага, это уже совсем другая лига :) Учите Spring в частности, и Dependency Injection в общем.

Comment: @Владислав, интерфейсы сами по себе просты, а вот Dependency Injection фреймворки, это да. Не для новичков.

Comment: Алексей Шиманский, как раз дело в том, что этот интерфейс реализован совсем в другом классе, который вообще не задействован в том классе, где вот у меня и возник вопрос. Есть объявление интерфейса, далее просто вызывается при инициализации объекта другого типа, в моем примере MyClassTestInt. Просто не поманю, почему это не так выглядит, MyClassTestInt myClassTestInt = КлассРеализующийИнтерфейс.update(id, name, groupId);

Comment: @Eugene Krivenja, как раз изучаю и параллельно Spring, просто наткнулся на такой код, и впал в замешательство. :(

Comment: Как вариант почитать. http://www.seostella.com/ru/article/2012/02/12/ispolzovanie-annotacii-autowired-v-spring-3.html

Comment: Дополняйте ваш вопрос согласно [рекомендациям по ведению дискуссий на Stack Overflow](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/691/6), вместо публикации комментариев. Комментарии могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Автор упустил в вопросе самое главное: что это `Spring` и что поле класса аннотировано как `@Autowired`.

Что собственно говорит Spring-у: вставь сюда подходящую имплементацию интерфейса.

Это называется **Dependency Injection** (**DI**), когда зависимые объекты подставляются в другой объект без явной их инициализации в коде.

Comment: спасибо большое. Понял, что некорректно задал вопрос. Дело все в аннотации

Answer (score 4):

Допустим у нас есть интерфейс:

```
interface MyInterface {
    void method();
}
```

Чтобы начать им пользоваться нам потребуется его реализация. Есть несколько способов это сделать:

**Обычный класс:**

```
class MyClass implements MyInterface {
    public void method(){
        System.out.println("Hello world");
    }
}
```

**Анонимный класс:**

```
MyInterface instance = new MyInterface(){
    public void method(){
        System.out.println("Hello world");
    }
}
```

В виде **лямбды функции**. Для этого нужно чтобы интерфейс был функциональным, т.е содержал бы один метод. В данном примере, он таковым и является.

```
MyInterface instance = ()-> System.out.println("Hello world");
```

Есть еще вариант, без явного создания экземпляра данного класса, с использованием **прокси**:

```
MyInterface instance = (MyInterface) Proxy.newProxyInstance(
            ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader(), new Class<?>[]{MyInterface.class},
            new InvocationHandler() {
                @Override
                public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
                    System.out.println("hello world");
                    return null;
                }
            });
```

Comment: Спасибо, такой-то принцип реализации я понимаю :) Мне как раз неясен принцип, который описал выше. Class class = Interface.metod();